# Node.js doesnot connect with MySQL, PHPMyAdmin

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to login to a system which uses mysql to store username and password but the login page is in manager.js file as below:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var async = require('async');

var util = require('../utils/util');
var db = require('../utils/database');
var connection = db.connection();

router.get('/login', function (req, res) {
  if (req.session.manager) {
    return res.redirect('/');
  }

  if (req.query.tip == 'error') {
    var tip = 'username or password incorrect!';
  } else {
    var tip = null;
  }
  res.render('login', { tip: tip });
});

router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM restaurant_accounts WHERE ra_name=?';
  connection.query(sql, [username], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (result.length == 0) {
      return res.redirect('/manager/login?tip=error');
    } 
    var account = result[0];
    if (!util.checkHash(password, account.ra_password)) {
      return res.redirect('/manager/login?tip=error');
    }

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE rest_owner_id=?', [account.ra_id], function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var restaurant = result[0];
      req.session.manager = {
        id: account.ra_id,
        name: account.ra_name,
        rest_id: restaurant.rest_id,
        rest_name: restaurant.rest_name
      };
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
});

router.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
  req.session.destroy();
  res.redirect('/manager/login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I type localhost:80 on my browser and run the express server it displays the following screen:

[image]

Now the username and password are supposed to be stored in mysql database created by somebody else and I use phpmyadmin to add database and have full access to it. But ofcourse since the database is not linked, I can't get past this login page and it shows the "**localhost** refused to connect" error!

Following is my console output **before I try to login to the page**:

```
C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server>node bin\www
Express server listening on port 80
GET /manager/login 304 23ms
GET /css/bootstrap.css 304 7ms
GET /css/main.css 304 6ms
GET /js/jquery.min.js 304 11ms
GET /images/bg.jpg 304 2ms
```

and when I type random username and password following is the output:

```
C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server>node bin\www
Express server listening on port 80
GET /manager/login 304 23ms
GET /css/bootstrap.css 304 7ms
GET /css/main.css 304 6ms
GET /js/jquery.min.js 304 11ms
GET /images/bg.jpg 304 2ms
C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\web\manager.js:27
    if (err) throw err;
             ^

Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'bjtu'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:51:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:103:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:74:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:109:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:141:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:41)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:136:18)
    at Connection._implyConnect (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:467:10)
    at Connection.query (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:212:8)
    at Object.handle (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\web\manager.js:26:14)
    at next_layer (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:103:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:107:5)
    at C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:195:24
    at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:251:12)

C:\Mrestro\RESTaurant_backend-master\rest-server>
```

So, my question is what username and password should I use? Where can I find the correct one in the database?

**EDIT:** database.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var c = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
 // port     : '3306',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
  database : 'restaurant'

});

// enable error logging for each connection query
c.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err.code); // example : 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR'
});

exports.connection = function() {
    return c;
};
```

Comment: Don't confuse the login here with your database credentials. That are two separate things. So find out where you need to add your DB credentials in this code and start of with filling your credentials from phpmyadmin there to see if it is working. To login here you need a username/password from this system. That's probably in the manual or installation instructions.

Comment: there is err with utils/database file can you show us that.

Comment: Yes, I've addedn the database.js file in the edit above.

Comment: I tried logging into manager.js with username and password as 'root' as given in database.js file but it shows username or password incorrect message.

Comment: @owaishanif786 I have one last problem, will you please help me out? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @owaishanif786 Hey, I'm having trouble creating the password again. I write the required password in the .js file, then 'localhost/manager/hash' to get the hashed password and use it in the password field in the database, but that password is not working to login. I created one entry on my own, then this problem started! Please help me, I really need this!

Comment: @owaishanif786 Just writing the steps here is also ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the ../utils/database set username to "root" and leave password empty or "" as it's default setting in windows lamp and xamp settings.
**EDIT**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var c = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
 // port     : '3306',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'restaurant'

});

// enable error logging for each connection query
c.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err.code); // example : 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR'
});

exports.connection = function() {
    return c;
};
```

Comment: Yes, I've added the database.js file in the edit above.

Comment: The login page does not accept an empty password field. It shows error: "Please fill out this field."

Comment: which login page?
goto localhost/phpmyadmin and check what credentials working over there

Comment: The tables are empty in database. The credentials need to be added in database in phpmyadmin. But the username and password set over there doesn't work on the login page. What am I not getting here?

Comment: just answer this simple thing. what are the username and password when you go to this page "localhost/phpmyadmin" i am not asking application or any other password.

Comment: The username is 'root' and the password is empty, but when I do that in the login page of manager.js it asks to enter sth in the password field and says it can't be left empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121178/discussion-between-owaishanif786-and-bik).